# Rewrite Magento Core Block

Tags: php, magento, module, url-rewriting

I have made a Module to rewrite `Mage_Core_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`, where I want to change the `getJSConfig` method.

```
class DennisKirkebak_ConfigurableStock_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
```

This is my Configurable.php class, which I have put in DennisKirkebak/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/ :

My config.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <denniskirkebak_catalog>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </denniskirkebak_catalog>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view_type_configurable>
                    DennisKirkebak_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
                </product_view_type_configurable>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

I have made my Module active in the app/code/etc/modules/ where I have a file called DennisKirkebak_All.xml and I can see my module in the backend of Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a var_dump() on this in some random template you know will get outputted:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/blocks/catalog/rewrite/product_view_type_configurable');
```

I'm not completely sure about that last part, if you're supposed to keep is as underscored or possibly separate it with slashes - but you get the point.  It will show you any active overrides at runtime, and let you know if there's some existing module that is already overriding the same block.

Answer (score 0):

Your block class names do not match up. Replace the part in your `config.xml` with this:

```
<product_view_type_configurable>DennisKirkebak_ConfigurableStock_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
```

Also I've noticed Magento sometimes behaves funny when you wrap the lines in your xml files, so try to keep it on one line